# Resetting styles added by JavaScript in onclick function

Tags: javascript, html

I started coding last week so I'm still very new at this.
I made a 3x3 grid and I want to expand that grid in each direction with an onclick function, which I've sort of done. But I don't know how to add a reset button. I want the reset button to set the 3x3 grid back to normal size.

Any help is appreciated

```js
function skråv(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8598';
}

function skråvut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function opp(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8593';
}

function opput(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function skråh(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8599';
}

function skråhut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function venstre(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8592';
}

function venstreut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function midt(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#10005';
}

function midtut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function høyre(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8594';
}

function høreut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function skrånedv(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8601';
}

function skrånedvut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function ned(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8595';
}

function nedut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function skrånedh(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8600';
}

function skrånedhut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function klikkright() {
  document.getElementById("right").style.paddingRight = "100px";
}

function klikkleft() {
  document.getElementById("left").style.paddingLeft = "100px";
}

function klikkopp() {
  document.getElementById("up").style.paddingTop = "100px";
}

function klikkned() {
  document.getElementById("down").style.paddingBottom = "100px";
}
```

```css
#white:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 13);
}

#blue:hover {
  background-color: rgb(147, 33, 240);
}

.rutenett td {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 70px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#blue {
  background-color: rgb(52, 164, 255);
}

table,
td {
  border: 10px inset grey;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#white {
  background-color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: ;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>3x3 GRID</h1>
  <table class="rutenett">
    <tr>
      <td id="blue" onmouseover="skråv(this)" onmouseout="skråvut(this)"></td>
      <td id="up" onmouseover="opp(this)" onmouseout="opput(this)" onclick="klikkopp(this)"></td>
      <td id="blue" onmouseover="skråh(this)" onmouseout="skråhut(this)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="left" onmouseover="venstre(this)" onmouseout="venstreut(this)" onclick="klikkleft(this)"></td>
      <td id="blue" onmouseover="midt(this)" onmouseout="midtut(this)"></td>
      <td id="right" onmouseover="høyre(this)" onmouseout="høreut(this)" onclick="klikkright(this)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="blue" onmouseover="skrånedv(this)" onmouseout="skrånedvut(this)"></td>
      <td id="down" onmouseover="ned(this)" onmouseout="nedut(this)" onclick="klikkned(this)"></td>
      <td id="blue" onmouseover="skrånedh(this)" onmouseout="skrånedhut(this)"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
```

Comment: Instead of using separate functions for each square, it would be more efficient to use the same one as the actions performed on each are similar. It's also preferable to use classes to add styling rather than doing it in the code. These are things you will learn as you go along :) And a bonus of using classes is that it makes it much easier to use them in an action (such as reset) than having to undo the styles added in the code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this way you can use the **button in the center** (the X) as **reset** button:

HTML:

```js
function skråv(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8598';
}

function skråvut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function opp(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8593';
}

function opput(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function skråh(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8599';
}

function skråhut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function venstre(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8592';
}

function venstreut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function midt(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#10005';
}

function midtut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function høyre(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8594';
}

function høreut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function skrånedv(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8601';
}

function skrånedvut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function ned(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8595';
}

function nedut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function skrånedh(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8600';
}

function skrånedhut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function klikkright() {
  document.getElementById("right").style.paddingRight = "100px";
}

function klikkleft() {
  document.getElementById("left").style.paddingLeft = "100px";
}

function klikkopp() {
  document.getElementById("up").style.paddingTop = "100px";
}

function klikkned() {
  document.getElementById("down").style.paddingBottom = "100px";
}

function reset() {
  document.getElementById("down").style.padding = "0px";
  document.getElementById("right").style.padding = "0px";
  document.getElementById("left").style.padding = "0px";
  document.getElementById("up").style.padding = "0px";
}
```

```css
#white:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 13);
}

#blue:hover {
  background-color: rgb(147, 33, 240);
}

.rutenett td {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 70px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#blue {
  background-color: rgb(52, 164, 255);
}

table,
td {
  border: 10px inset grey;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#white {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<table class="rutenett">
  <tr>
    <td id="blue" onmouseover="skråv(this)" onmouseout="skråvut(this)"></td>
    <td id="up" onmouseover="opp(this)" onmouseout="opput(this)" onclick="klikkopp(this)"></td>
    <td id="blue" onmouseover="skråh(this)" onmouseout="skråhut(this)"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="left" onmouseover="venstre(this)" onmouseout="venstreut(this)" onclick="klikkleft(this)"></td>
    <td id="blue" onmouseover="midt(this)" onmouseout="midtut(this)" onclick="reset();"></td>
    <td id="right" onmouseover="høyre(this)" onmouseout="høreut(this)" onclick="klikkright(this)"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="blue" onmouseover="skrånedv(this)" onmouseout="skrånedvut(this)"></td>
    <td id="down" onmouseover="ned(this)" onmouseout="nedut(this)" onclick="klikkned(this)"></td>
    <td id="blue" onmouseover="skrånedh(this)" onmouseout="skrånedhut(this)"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note:
You should not assign the same value to the **id**, the ids are unique identifiers and the same value could generate anomalies during the management of the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

**You can do this much more efficiently with classes and a single click function:**

- Using classes gives you much more flexibility over have styles you can add.
- Using a single click function removes the repetition of almost-identical functions, and also makes it easier to change in future
- The classes also make it very easy to clear all the styles with your reset button

**1. Create classes for each expanded style**, e.g.

```
td.expandright { padding-right:100px;}
td.expandleft  { padding-left:100px;}
td.expandup    { padding-top:100px;}
td.expanddown  { padding-bottom:100px;}
```

**2. One function to process clicks on all squares** You can replace all 4 of your klikk functions with just this one that uses the id of the clicked square and add the appropriate CSS class:

```
function klikk(clickedsquare) {
  clickedsquare.classList.add("expand"+clickedsquare.id);
}
```

You already pass the clicked element into your function as a parameter, so we can use this (`clickedsquare`) to get the id using `clickedsquare.id` (e.g. "right") and then create the classname bt adding this to "expand", e.g. `expandright`, and add this to the square.

**3. Then you can reset them all simply by removing the class** from all the squares. This gets all your `td`s and removes the classes starting with "expand", resetting the styles:

```
function reset(){
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {        // go through each td
        inputs[i].classList.forEach(className => {  // check each class
           if (className.startsWith('expand'))      // if it starts with "expand"...
             inputs[i].classList.remove(className); //... remove it
        });
    }
}
```

**Working Snippet** (Note this fixes the non-unique ids):

```js
function reset() {
  // get all td elements
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  
  // loop through each ed 
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    // inputs[i].className=""; /* this will remove ALL classes */

    // remove classes starting with "expand"
    inputs[i].classList.forEach(className => {
      // check for classes starting with "expand"
      if (className.startsWith('expand'))
        inputs[i].classList.remove(className);
    });
  }
}

function klikk(clickedsquare) {
  clickedsquare.classList.add("expand" + clickedsquare.id);
}

function skråv(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8598';
}

function skråvut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function opp(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8593';
}

function opput(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function skråh(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8599';
}

function skråhut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function venstre(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8592';
}

function venstreut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function midt(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#10005';
}

function midtut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function høyre(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8594';
}

function høreut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function skrånedv(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8601';
}

function skrånedvut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function ned(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8595';
}

function nedut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function skrånedh(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8600';
}

function skrånedhut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}
```

```css
#white:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 13);
}

.blue:hover {
  background-color: rgb(147, 33, 240);
}

.rutenett td {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 70px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.blue {
  background-color: rgb(52, 164, 255);
}

table,
td {
  border: 10px inset grey;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#white {
  background-color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: ;
}

td.expandright {
  padding-right: 100px;
}

td.expandleft {
  padding-left: 100px;
}

td.expandup {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

td.expanddown {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>3x3 GRID</h1>
  <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
  <table class="rutenett">
    <tr>
      <td class="blue" onmouseover="skråv(this)" onmouseout="skråvut(this)"></td>
      <td id="up" onmouseover="opp(this)" onmouseout="opput(this)" onclick="klikk(this)"></td>
      <td class="blue" onmouseover="skråh(this)" onmouseout="skråhut(this)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="left" onmouseover="venstre(this)" onmouseout="venstreut(this)" onclick="klikk(this)"></td>
      <td class="blue" onmouseover="midt(this)" onmouseout="midtut(this)"  onclick="reset()"></td> <!-- reset on click -->
      <td id="right" onmouseover="høyre(this)" onmouseout="høreut(this)" onclick="klikk(this)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="blue" onmouseover="skrånedv(this)" onmouseout="skrånedvut(this)"></td>
      <td id="down" onmouseover="ned(this)" onmouseout="nedut(this)" onclick="klikk(this)"></td>
      <td class="blue" onmouseover="skrånedh(this)" onmouseout="skrånedhut(this)"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
```

**UPDATE**: Note that ids must be unique, so I have changed your "blue" id to a class in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding paddings to each side you can set them to 0.

```js
function skråv(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8598';
}

function skråvut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function opp(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8593';
}

function opput(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function skråh(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8599';
}

function skråhut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function venstre(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8592';
}

function venstreut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function midt(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#10005';
}

function midtut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function høyre(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8594';
}

function høreut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function skrånedv(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8601';
}

function skrånedvut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function ned(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8595';
}

function nedut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function skrånedh(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8600';
}

function skrånedhut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function reset(){
    document.getElementById("down").style.paddingBottom = "0px";
    document.getElementById("right").style.paddingRight = "0px";
    document.getElementById("left").style.paddingLeft = "0px";
    document.getElementById("up").style.paddingTop = "0px";

}


function klikkright() {
  document.getElementById("right").style.paddingRight = "100px";
}

function klikkleft() {
  document.getElementById("left").style.paddingLeft = "100px";
}

function klikkopp() {
  document.getElementById("up").style.paddingTop = "100px";
}

function klikkned() {
  document.getElementById("down").style.paddingBottom = "100px";
}
```

```css
#white:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 13);
}

#blue:hover {
  background-color: rgb(147, 33, 240);
}

.rutenett td {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 70px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#blue {
  background-color: rgb(52, 164, 255);
}

table,
td {
  border: 10px inset grey;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#white {
  background-color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: ;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>3x3 GRID</h1>
  <button onclick="reset()">
  reset
</button>
  <table class="rutenett">
    <tr>
      <td id="blue" onmouseover="skråv(this)" onmouseout="skråvut(this)"></td>
      <td id="up" onmouseover="opp(this)" onmouseout="opput(this)" onclick="klikkopp(this)"></td>
      <td id="blue" onmouseover="skråh(this)" onmouseout="skråhut(this)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="left" onmouseover="venstre(this)" onmouseout="venstreut(this)" onclick="klikkleft(this)"></td>
      <td id="blue" onmouseover="midt(this)" onmouseout="midtut(this)"></td>
      <td id="right" onmouseover="høyre(this)" onmouseout="høreut(this)" onclick="klikkright(this)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="blue" onmouseover="skrånedv(this)" onmouseout="skrånedvut(this)"></td>
      <td id="down" onmouseover="ned(this)" onmouseout="nedut(this)" onclick="klikkned(this)"></td>
      <td id="blue" onmouseover="skrånedh(this)" onmouseout="skrånedhut(this)"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead,

Table center button **X** click to reset. Add `resetall()` function to it's `onclick` event.

```
function resetall(){

  // to get all td in table rutrnett
  var all = document.querySelectorAll(".rutenett td");

  // used a loop to set padding 10px initial state
  for(i=0;i<all.length;i++){

    //get all td item in a variable
    var alltd = all[i];

    //setting padding to 10px
    alltd.style.padding = "10px";

  }
}
```

click **Show code snippet** to show code.

```js
function skråv(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8598';
}

function skråvut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function opp(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8593';
}

function opput(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function skråh(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8599';
}

function skråhut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function venstre(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8592';
}

function venstreut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function midt(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#10005';
}

function midtut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function høyre(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8594';
}

function høreut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function skrånedv(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8601';
}

function skrånedvut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function ned(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8595';
}

function nedut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function skrånedh(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8600';
}

function skrånedhut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function klikkright() {
  document.getElementById("right").style.paddingRight = "100px";
}

function klikkleft() {
  document.getElementById("left").style.paddingLeft = "100px";
}

function klikkopp() {
  document.getElementById("up").style.paddingTop = "100px";
}

function klikkned() {
  document.getElementById("down").style.paddingBottom = "100px";
}
function resetall(){
  var all = document.querySelectorAll(".rutenett td");
  for(i=0;i<all.length;i++){
    var alltd = all[i];
    alltd.style.padding = "10px";
  }
}
```

```css
#white:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 13);
}

#blue:hover {
  background-color: rgb(147, 33, 240);
}

.rutenett td {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 70px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#blue {
  background-color: rgb(52, 164, 255);
}

table,
td {
  border: 10px inset grey;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#white {
  background-color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: ;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>3x3 GRID</h1>
  <table class="rutenett">
    <tr>
      <td id="blue" onmouseover="skråv(this)" onmouseout="skråvut(this)"></td>
      <td id="up" onmouseover="opp(this)" onmouseout="opput(this)" onclick="klikkopp(this)"></td>
      <td id="blue" onmouseover="skråh(this)" onmouseout="skråhut(this)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="left" onmouseover="venstre(this)" onmouseout="venstreut(this)" onclick="klikkleft(this)"></td>
      <td id="blue" onmouseover="midt(this)" onmouseout="midtut(this)" onclick="resetall()"></td>
      <td id="right" onmouseover="høyre(this)" onmouseout="høreut(this)" onclick="klikkright(this)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="blue" onmouseover="skrånedv(this)" onmouseout="skrånedvut(this)"></td>
      <td id="down" onmouseover="ned(this)" onmouseout="nedut(this)" onclick="klikkned(this)"></td>
      <td id="blue" onmouseover="skrånedh(this)" onmouseout="skrånedhut(this)"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to select all the elements that you want to revert back in a single variable. This way you can call a function which loops over these elements and removes the styles for each one of them.

But first you'll need a way to identify those elements. In the example below I've added the `.direction` class for the arrows up, down, left and right. Now I know which elements I need to select.

With [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) you can search for elements in the HTML and select them. This method will give a list of elements that have been found by your query. For example: If you want to find all the elements with the `class="direction"` attribute like I've added, then we should do the following:

```
const directions = document.querySelectorAll('.direction');
```

This line will look for all `.direction` elements and return them in a list. Now you have something to loop over.

Create a function which will reset the styles that you've added in the other functions. Inside this function create a loop which loops over all the items in the `directions` constant. The example below uses a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop which is a modern way of looping and can be used for our list of elements.

```
function resetGrid() {
  for (const direction of directions) {
    direction.style.padding = '0px'
  }
}
```

In the the loop there is a new constant defined for each item in your loop. So what you are seeing **in** the loop is what happens to every individual element. In this case it's setting the padding back to `0px`.

All you have to do now is have a trigger for the function to run. Something like the X in the middle of your grid. Select that element as well, but use [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). The difference with `querySelectorAll()` is that `querySelector()` only looks for the first occurrence of an element instead of all occurrences.

First this case too it helps to have a way to identify the element that you are looking for. So I've added the `id="reset"` attribute to the center element. Mind that all ID's have to be unique, otherwise they are useless. It's like having the same social security number as somebody else, and you don't want that.

```
const reset = document.querySelector('#reset')
```

Now you've got your reset element. Instead of adding `onclick` on the element itself use JavaScript to do that. This is a good practice to learn and will keep your JavaScript in one place and your HTML in another. Same goes for CSS. Separation is good and helps you to stay organized!

With [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) you can listen for event on an element. Every element can do this and can listen for a range of events. In this case you'll want to listen for the `'click'` event and call the `resetGrid` function whenever it has been clicked. This should look like the example down here.

```
reset.addEventListener('click', resetGrid);
```

I've made a working example which does everything described above. It's great that you are learning. Keep coming back to SO if you need anything else!

```js
const directions = document.querySelectorAll('.direction');
const reset = document.querySelector('#reset');

function resetGrid() {
  for (const direction of directions) {
    direction.style.padding = '0px'
  }
}

reset.addEventListener('click', resetGrid);

function skråv(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8598';
}

function skråvut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function opp(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8593';
}

function opput(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function skråh(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8599';
}

function skråhut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function venstre(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8592';
}

function venstreut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function midt(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#10005';
}

function midtut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function høyre(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8594';
}

function høreut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function skrånedv(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8601';
}

function skrånedvut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function ned(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8595';
}

function nedut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function skrånedh(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8600';
}

function skrånedhut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function klikkright() {
  document.getElementById("right").style.paddingRight = "100px";
}

function klikkleft() {
  document.getElementById("left").style.paddingLeft = "100px";
}

function klikkopp() {
  document.getElementById("up").style.paddingTop = "100px";
}

function klikkned() {
  document.getElementById("down").style.paddingBottom = "100px";
}
```

```css
.rutenett td {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 70px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

table,
td {
  border: 10px inset grey;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}

.white:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 13);
}

.blue {
  background-color: rgb(52, 164, 255);
}

.blue:hover {
  background-color: rgb(147, 33, 240);
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: ;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>3x3 GRID</h1>
  <table class="rutenett">
    <tr>
      <td class="blue" onmouseover="skråv(this)" onmouseout="skråvut(this)"></td>
      <td class="direction" id="up" onmouseover="opp(this)" onmouseout="opput(this)" onclick="klikkopp(this)"></td>
      <td class="blue" onmouseover="skråh(this)" onmouseout="skråhut(this)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="direction" id="left" onmouseover="venstre(this)" onmouseout="venstreut(this)" onclick="klikkleft(this)"></td>
      <td class="blue" id="reset" onmouseover="midt(this)" onmouseout="midtut(this)"></td>
      <td class="direction" id="right" onmouseover="høyre(this)" onmouseout="høreut(this)" onclick="klikkright(this)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="blue" onmouseover="skrånedv(this)" onmouseout="skrånedvut(this)"></td>
      <td class="direction" id="down" onmouseover="ned(this)" onmouseout="nedut(this)" onclick="klikkned(this)"></td>
      <td class="blue" onmouseover="skrånedh(this)" onmouseout="skrånedhut(this)"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

You can keep the original table via a variable. And insert the original version to reset it.

```js
const table =  document.querySelector(".rutenett").innerHTML;

function reset(){
  document.querySelector(".rutenett").innerHTML = table;
}

function skråv(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8598';
}

function skråvut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function opp(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8593';
}

function opput(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function skråh(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8599';
}

function skråhut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function venstre(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8592';
}

function venstreut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function midt(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#10005';
}

function midtut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function høyre(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8594';
}

function høreut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function skrånedv(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8601';
}

function skrånedvut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function ned(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8595';
}

function nedut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function skrånedh(inn) {
  inn.innerHTML = '&#8600';
}

function skrånedhut(out) {
  out.innerHTML = '';
}

function klikkright() {
  document.getElementById("right").style.paddingRight = "100px";
}

function klikkleft() {
  document.getElementById("left").style.paddingLeft = "100px";
}

function klikkopp() {
  document.getElementById("up").style.paddingTop = "100px";
}

function klikkned() {
  document.getElementById("down").style.paddingBottom = "100px";
}
```

```css
#white:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 13);
}

#blue:hover {
  background-color: rgb(147, 33, 240);
}

.rutenett td {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 70px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#blue {
  background-color: rgb(52, 164, 255);
}

table,
td {
  border: 10px inset grey;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#white {
  background-color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: ;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>3x3 GRID</h1>
  <table class="rutenett">
    <tr>
      <td id="blue" onmouseover="skråv(this)" onmouseout="skråvut(this)"></td>
      <td id="up" onmouseover="opp(this)" onmouseout="opput(this)" onclick="klikkopp(this)"></td>
      <td id="blue" onmouseover="skråh(this)" onmouseout="skråhut(this)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="left" onmouseover="venstre(this)" onmouseout="venstreut(this)" onclick="klikkleft(this)"></td>
      <td id="blue" onmouseover="midt(this)" onmouseout="midtut(this)"></td>
      <td id="right" onmouseover="høyre(this)" onmouseout="høreut(this)" onclick="klikkright(this)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="blue" onmouseover="skrånedv(this)" onmouseout="skrånedvut(this)"></td>
      <td id="down" onmouseover="ned(this)" onmouseout="nedut(this)" onclick="klikkned(this)"></td>
      <td id="blue" onmouseover="skrånedh(this)" onmouseout="skrånedhut(this)"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<button id="reset" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
</body>
```